# Airflow MySQL operator trying to execute script path string as SQL, rather than using template

Tags: mysql, airflow

I've got a confusing issue on Airflow which I don't understand.

I have a SQL scripts folder at DML/analytics/my_script.sql. The MySQL operator works perfectly in normal circumstances, but does not when I try to call it from a Python operator as follows. This is necessitated by needing to pass in XCOM values from another task:

```
def insert_func(**kwargs):
    run_update = MySqlOperator(
        sql='DML/analytics/my_script.sql',
        task_id='insert_func',
        mysql_conn_id="bi_mysql",
        params={
            "table_name": table_name, 
            'ts': kwargs['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key='return_value',task_ids='get_existing_data')
        },
    )
    run_update.execute(context=kwargs['task_instance'])

with DAG("my_dag", **dag_params) as dag:
    with TaskGroup(group_id='insert') as insert:
        get_existing_data = PythonOperator(
            task_id='get_existing_data',
            python_callable=MySQLGetRecord,
            op_kwargs={
                'target_db_conn_id':'bi_mysql', 
                'target_db':'analytics', 
                'sql': f'SELECT invoice_date FROM analytics.{table_name} ORDER BY 1 DESC'
            }
        ),
        insert = PythonOperator(
            task_id='insert',
            python_callable=insert_func
        )
        get_existing_data >> insert_func
```

The error I get is: `MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DML/analytics/my_script.sql' at line 1")`

Clearly it is trying to run the literal string passed in the `sql` parameter rather than using it as a file location. Why is this happening? Again, this works if I move the `run_update` task to the my_dag `with` clause, but I need to do it this way to get the XCOM value from `get_existing_data`, correct...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using operator as normal (e.g to be used by Airflow) then Airflow is responsible for the whole task lifecycle. This means Airflow handles the templating, executing `pre_execute()`, executing `execute()`, executing on_faulure/retries etc...

What you did is using operator inside operator -> `PythonOperator` that contains `MySqlOperator`. In this case the inner operator (`MySqlOperator`) is just a regular Python class. While it's called Operator - it's is not a "real" Operator.
You are not enjoying any of the lifecycle steps as you might expect.

You might have already realised it as by your own example you specifically triggered the `execute()`:

```
run_update.execute(context=kwargs['task_instance'])
```

Notice you didn't need to do this for the `PythonOperaor`.

You can see in the code base that Airflow invokes [`render_templates`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e82a2fdf841dd571f3b8f456c4d054cf3a94fc03/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1555) before it invokes `pre_execute()` and before it invokes [execute()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e82a2fdf841dd571f3b8f456c4d054cf3a94fc03/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1598).

This means that if you want the `MySqlOperator` to be templated you need to call the function that does the templating before you invoke the `execute()`

That said - I strongly encourage you - Do not use operator inside operator.

From your code I don't see reason why you can't just use `MySqlOperator` directly without the `PythonOperaor` but should there be a reason the proper way to handle it is to create a `CustomMySqlOperator` that handles the logic you seek. By doing so you will not have problems with using `.sql` files.