# Jinja Airflow 2.2

Tags: python, airflow, task, operator-keyword, airflow-2.x

I'm currently trying to find the best way of creating multiple PodOperators in Airflow 2.2.3 (Partial/Expand Pods not available yet) using on a `xcom.pull`.

The content of `"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='any_previous_task') }}"` is a list, which is already handled as `str` and I already tried couple of ways to convert it, like

- `ast.literal_eval`
- `eval`
- Adding Jinja type, `| list`

None of above methods worked. The only way which works is by calling a PythonOperator, however, defining an Operator inside another operator [is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71998282/airflow-mysql-operator-trying-to-execute-script-path-string-as-sql-rather-than/71998563#71998563)

Here's a piece of code

```
    operators = []
    prev_val = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='any_previous_task') }}"
    if prev_val:
        o = BashOperator(
            task_id='task_test',
            bash_command="echo 'TYPE {}, CONTENT {} <<<< was executed '".format(type(prev_val), prev_val),
            dag=dag
        )
    operators.append(o)   

start >> operators
```

Comment: you should use BranchPythonOperator to call the BashOperator. you are mixing here code from when parsing Dag (if prev_val) and on execution time (jinja). implemnt BranchPythonOperator that checks the Jinja on execute