Use parametrized query in Airflow DAG for OracleToGCSOperator
I have a DAG that looks like below, that gets executed via Cloud Composer. Its purpose is to extract data from an Oracle database. I try to have parametrized approach to the operator to avoid code duplication. The query is loaded from a GCS bucket and then I would expect that the parameters from it to be replace at runtime as specified in the operator.
with DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag_id',
    default_args=default_args
    ) as dag:
    
    def get_data_from_oracle(my_table, **context):
    
        my_hook = GCSHook()
        query = my_hook.download_as_byte_array(
            bucket_name = 'my_bucket',
            object_name = 'my_sql.sql'
        ).decode()
        
        my_operator = OracleToGCSOperator(
            task_id = f'extract_data_from_{my_table}',
            oracle_conn_id = my_oracle_connection,
            sql = f'{query}',
            bucket = 'my_bucket',
            filename = 'my_file.parquet',
            parameters = {
                'table_name': f'{my_table}'
            },
            export_format='PARQUET'
        )
        
        operator.execute(context)
        
    move_data_for_x_table = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'move_data_for_x_table',
        python_callable = get_data_from_oracle,
        op_kwargs = {
            my_table = 'x'
        }
    )

.sql file looks like this:
SELECT * FROM {{ table_name }}

When executed, the variable in the query is not replaced and Oracle throws ORA-00911: invalid character.

The pattern of operator inside operator is bad practice and will not work in your case. You are expecting the inner operator to be run templating but Airflow does not recognize it as operator. You can read more about it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71998563/14624409
The issue is that OracleToGCSOperator can't read .sql file that stored remotely. As you figured out you need to download the .sql file and then use it. You need to create custom operator that handle this, the execute() function needs to download the sql file and run templating over it then it will work as you expect.
